# create a mobile app from my web site using reactjs (not native)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, webpack, mobile-application

I need to develop a mobile application which will be same for my web site (already create with reactjs). I was researching on reactjs. Can I convert my reactjs code from web-site to reactjs for mobile application ?

need a solution please
Thanks

Comment: It's not possible to create a mobile application using ReactJS. Either you have to use react native or you can create a Progressive Web App or you can use WebView inside an application.

Answer (score 5):

No bro, a PWA cannot be uploaded to the apple store, by the way you can bypass this problem using ionic capacitator!

> Capacitor is a cross-platform app runtime that makes it easy to build
> web apps that run natively on iOS, Android, Electron, and the web. We
> call these apps “Native Progressive Web Apps” and they represent the
> next evolution beyond Hybrid apps.

According with this tutorial written by [Manish Mandal](https://medium.com/how-to-react/convert-your-existing-react-js-app-to-android-or-ios-app-using-the-ionic-capacitor-a127deda75bd) to do so u have to:

1 - First, go to the root of your existing react app and create a file capacitor.config.json and inside that put the below code

```
{
  "appId": "io.ionic.yourapp",
  "appName": "yourapp",
  "bundledWebRuntime": false,
  "npmClient": "npm",
  "webDir": "build",
  "cordova": {}
}
```

2 - Now create another file name ionic.config.json and inside that insert the below code.

```
{
  "name": "yourapp",
  "integrations": {
    "capacitor": {}
  },
  "type": "react"
}
```

3 - Now we need to build our react project. To build your react app open your terminal to the root of the project and run the below-mentioned command

```
npm run build
```

> Note: this will create the build folder in your root porject and the
> name of the folder should match the webDir name inside
> capacitor.config.json file

4 - Now we will install ionic globally in our machine. To install ionic globally in your machine open your terminal and run the below command.

```
npm install -g @ionic/cli
```

5 - Now install the capacitor core in our project.

```
npm install @capacitor/core --save
```

**ANDROID**

6 - After that, we will first create an android app with our existing react app. Open your terminal and type

```
ionic capacitor add android
```

This will create the android folder in your root project and install all the required dependencies.

7 - Now run the below command to open your android project in android studio.

```
npx cap open android
```

Wait some time and then it will ask you to update the Gradle. Just update the Gradle to the latest version and run the project in the emulator. You can also connect your mobile to run the project live on your mobile phone.

8 - Now open the build menu from the android studio and build your apk file.

**IOS**

9 - To create ios app run the below command

```
ionic capacitor add ios
```

This will install all the required dependencies and ios folder to your project.

10 - Now run the below command to open your ios project in Xcode.

```
npx cap open ios
```

11 - Now open the app in emulator or physical device and build the app.

---

More info about capacitator:
https://capacitorjs.com/

Answer (score 3):

so you need to create progressive web app , all it takes a `mainfest.json` file in your meta tag [WebApp Manifest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Manifest)

with some splash screens and icons chrome will make you install mobile app like on client devices. And try to implement a service worker to handle the offline mode [Service Worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Manifest)

This course from egghead is very good [PWA](https://egghead.io/courses/progressive-web-apps-in-react-with-create-react-app)

Comment: Many thanks abdoutelb, i heard that PWA should be used in Production mode, is it true?

Comment: @mitsu it has been used for a long time and a lot of companies published their pwa ... you can check instagram or twitter pwa.

Comment: i've tried many examples, but they all says that i have to be in production mode :(

Comment: @mitsu you can remove the `process.env.NODE_ENV== "production"` from serviceWorker.js and develop the service worker though development.
and you can use workbox

Answer (score 2):

You could create an "app" that is really just a webview that shows your website but it won't really have the same experience as a native app.

As mentioned a PWA would be a good approach. This way you can keep all your ReactJS code and have an app-like experience.
Android even supports [submitting PWAs to the store](https://medium.com/@firt/google-play-store-now-open-for-progressive-web-apps-ec6f3c6ff3cc).

Answer (score 1):

You can't perform code conversion from react-js to react native directly, even though there are many similarities between them. Web application built with React.js can be easily converted to a React Native mobile app, and some source code can be reused

if you want to develop a single app for both mobile and web either,

create a web app that mobile browser friendly

or

create PWA(Progressive Web app) using React, PWA can access Native Mobile api like GPS